# Debugging a program update - "from_bytes_mut>SizeMismatch"

Tags: anchor, solana-program, debug

I have a working crowdsourcing onchain program that works well, but I wanted to expand upon one aspect to add a u64. When doing so, I seem to be getting hit with a from_bytes_mut>SizeMismatch, but I can't quite figure out why. I've combed through and ensured that the space I'm setting is enough for the new u64 (an additional 8bytes) but still getting the error.

The error message points out src/lib.rs line 119:3 but that line is a blank line in between two structs.

This is the place where the error first pops up after I've edited to account for the u64. Here's im just hardcoding a 1:

```
let investor_ata = &ctx.accounts.investor_ata;
        let data = &mut ctx.accounts.data.load_mut()?;
        let new_id: u64 = 1; //hardcoding to 1
        data.events[project.data_index as usize] = Investment{
            investor: *investor.key,
            investor_ata: investor_ata.key(),
            amount: ajusted_amount,
            new_id: new_id //This is the new u64
        };
```

Comment: It's tough to figure out exactly what's going on, but are you using an old account that has a smaller size from earlier development? You may need to reallocate smaller accounts, or start fresh with a new ledger, to be sure that all accounts are initialized with the right amount of space.